# Wrapping With Divs PHP Dom

Tags: php, dom

Could someone help me out.

I trying to get info from some page that the html looks like this.

```
<div class="block">
  <h2>Season 1</h2>
  <div class="episode"><a href="somelink.com">Episode 1</a></div>
  <div class="episode"><a href="somelink.com">Episode 2</a></div>
  <h2>Season 2</h2>
  <div class="episode"><a href="somelink.com">Episode 1</a></div>
</div>
```

But what i am stuck on is for every Season i want to wrap them in divs with the seasons episode inside the div for example

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="season">
      <h2>Season 1</h2>
      <div class="episode"><a href="somelink.com">Episode 1</a></div>
      <div class="episode"><a href="somelink.com">Episode 2</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="season">
      <h2>Season 2</h2>
      <div class="episode"><a href="somelink.com">Episode 1</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the PHP code i'm working with

```
$page = "someurl.com";

$page = $this->curl->get($page);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($page);

$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
for($i=0;$i<$divs->length;$i++){
  if ($divs->item($i)->getAttribute("class")=="block") {
    $h2s = $divs->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('h2');
    if (count($h2s) > 0) {
      foreach ($h2s as $h2) {
      // Stuck at this point
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can i do this in PHP DOM could someone please give me a example thanks.

Comment: Regardlass who might solve this for you, we all like you to try and show what you've tried in your question. This is so you can learn what you're doing wrong/incorrect.

Comment: What are you using to represent/parse the DOM structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below wraps each `<h2>` and its `.episode` siblings in `.season` container

```
   $page = '<div class="block">
      <h2>Season 1</h2>
      <div class="episode"><a href="s1ep1.com">Episode 1</a></div>
      <div class="episode"><a href="s1ep2.com">Episode 2</a></div>
      <h2>Season 2</h2>
      <div class="episode"><a href="s2ep1.com">Episode 1</a></div>
      <div class="episode"><a href="s2ep1.com">Episode 2</a></div>
    </div>';

  $dom = new DOMDocument();

  $origVal = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
  @$dom->loadHTML($page);
  libxml_clear_errors();
  libxml_use_internal_errors($origVal);

  //create a tmeplate 'season' div
  $season = $dom->createElement('div');
  $season->setAttribute('class', 'season');

  //get all '.block' divs using xpath
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
  $divs = $xpath->query("//*[@class='block']");

  $clones = array();
  $clone = '';

  foreach($divs as $currDiv) {

     //check if the 'block' contains any <h2> elemnts, if not, skip this block
     if(!count($currDiv->getElementsByTagName('h2'))) {
        continue;
     }

     foreach($currDiv->childNodes as $child) {

        if(in_array($child->nodeName, array(
                                           '#text',
                                           '#comment'
                                      ))
        ) {
           //ignore white space (and text content), and comments in 'block' div
           continue;
        }

        if($child->nodeName == 'h2') {
           if($clone) {
              //save all clones of 'season' template div in an array for further use
              $clones[] = $clone;
           }

           $clone = $season->cloneNode(true);
        }

        //this is the tricky part. If we do not append a clone of original div, then it actually moves the div to $clone. This changes HTML structure and disrupts the current loop
        //so we append the clones of child to the 'season' div
        if($child->nodeName == 'h2' || $child->getAttribute('class') == 'episode') {
           $clone->appendChild($child->cloneNode(true));
        }
     }
     $clones[] = $clone;

     //remove all children of current 'block' div
     while($currDiv->childNodes->length) {
        $currDiv->removeChild($currDiv->firstChild);
     }

     //isnert all 'season' nodes in it
     foreach($clones as $c) {
        $currDiv->appendChild($c);
     }
  }

  echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: i am really grateful for the time you spent writing this out. Works great thank you :)